# Problem with Google Chrome dock icon on 16.04

Tags: unity, google-chrome, launcher, icons, crash

My problem is that when I minimize a chrome window and I want to maximize it again by clicking the chrome icon in the dock for about a second everything looks like it's crashing (system interface disappears, so for a second I see nothing but my wallpaper) and then everything is back to normal but the windows didn't open, so I'm not able to open chrome windows that I minimized (or at least not when clicking the chrome icon in the dock). This only occurs with the chrome icon, everything else works fine. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after my whole unity crashed, meaning that I only saw my wallpaper at all times. What solved this for me was the top answer here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)